# How does one use Live Templates inside File Templates in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

I'm trying to change the default header in Intellij IDEA Community 2016.1

```
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

to have a date variable print an ISO 8601 date format instead of their usual platform-and-locale-dependent format. It's proving to be pretty damn difficult.

There's a configuration described in the [help file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-and-code-templates-2.html?origin=old_help#d1323850e289), *"Enable Live Templates"* which supposedly enables live template variable parsing in file templates, so I made a very simple live variable, made it work in the editor, but I can't figure out how to make it work in file templates, not even by looking at their source code. I brute-forced everything I've read about Velocity templates, escaping, $variable, $variable$, #set directives, and all the combinations above... No dice.

Does anybody know what's going on? Or am I wrong about what that checkbox does?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HTML file template that comes by default:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>#[[$Title$]]#</title>
</head>
<body>
#[[$END$]]#
</body>
</html>
```

Wrap your vars like `#[[$VAR$]]#`

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. All those "Live Templates" in templates just happen to be cursor markers, while the real "Live Templates" are shortcuts for code completion and generation. They don't seem to have anything to do with each other.